# How to display individual errors for each text field using ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

without using AJAX, I would normally do something like this ( I would usually use preg_match() but just using empty() for simplicity's sake)

```
$message = "";
if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $message. = "First name required <br/>";
}
if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
    $message. = "Last name required";
    if ($message) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$message.
        "</div>";
    } else {
        // write to db, send email etc.
    }
}
```

I am trying to use AJAX though with this. I did a bit myself and got help with some as well but the issue I have now is that I can only get on error message to display but I want to do what I did in the above example.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#send" ).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#send" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( ".loader" ).show();
    $( "#send" ).html( "Sending <img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'>" );
    var form_data = $( "#contact-form" ).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 't2329.php',
      data: form_data,
      dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function(response) {
      $( ".loader").hide();
      $( "#server-results" ).hide().html(response.message).fadeIn("slow");
      $('#send').html('Send Enquiry').prop({disabled: false});
      if (response.status) {
        $('#contact-form').hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<?php
if ($_POST) {
  $response = new stdClass;
  $response->message = "";
  $response->status = false;
  $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $response->status =  true;
  }

  if($response->status === false) {
    $response->message = <<< MSG
    <div class="red-error">
      <b>There were errors in your form:</b><br/>
      Invalid email address. <br/>
    </div>
MSG;
  } 
  else {
    // WRITE TO DB HERE
    // SEND EMAIL HERE
    $response->message = <<< MSG
    <div class="green-success">Thank you. We will respond to your enquiry as soon as possible.</div>
MSG;
  }

  die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: better to use jQuery validator:- https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/   .Very easy to use and lots of code will reduced.

Comment: I want to use server side validation though, not jquery validation.

Comment: No console errors

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend:

- you are using `JSON`, so return array of errors with proper field indexes instead of just `message`;
- do not return `HTML` from server - build proper `HTML` with `JavaScript`;
- `JavaScript` validation is nice but server side validation is always required;

  ```
  {
    errors: [
      {
        'field': 'email',
        'message': 'Some error'
      }, {
        'field': 'first_name',
        'message': 'Some error'
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

Comment: I am not too clued up on JSON. Where in relation to the code I posted would I put the JSON?

Comment: You are returning JSON: die(json_encode($response));